# MVC Routing Issue when trying www.example.com/id

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, routes

Let say I have a website  `www.example.com`

the default routing looks like

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Ok that works fine but let's say I want my site when I go to `www.example.com/id`  to go to `www.example.com/login/index/id`

How would I configure/add routing for this, without breaking my other pages where I am actually trying to go to `www.example.com/controller`?

**EDIT:** Unfortunately id is a string so I do not have any concrete constraints that I can think of that would work.  Think of maybe instead of the id I should have said companyname or sitename so the URL would look like www.example.com/companyname  .

The only solution that I have come up with so far is adding a maproute for each one of my controllers like this

```
 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Home",
        url: "Home/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);

 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "Settings",
        url: "Settings/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Settings", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

 routes.MapRoute(
        name: "companyname",
        url: "{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );

   routes.MapRoute(
        name: "default",
        url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
        defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
    );
```

This will work but I have many controllers and if I add one in the future and forget to adjust the routes it will fail. Also, this is unlikely but if a companyname happens to the be same as one of my controller names it would also fail.

Answer (score 0):

In controller you may redirect to another Controller/action:

```
public ActionResult yourAction()
{
  return  RedirectToAction("nameAction","nameController");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried adding this mapping first:

```
routes.MapRoute( name: "Custom", url: "{id}", defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional } );
```

That should work but keep in mind that routes are evaluated secuentially, so you will have to organize mappings in order to reach out all pages in your site.

For example, routes like www.example.com/Product could be redirected to /Login by mistake.

EDIT: You can add constraints, so if id is an int value, you can try with the following:

```
 routes.MapRoute("Custom", "{id}",
                new { controller = "Login", action = "Index" },
                new { id = @"\d+" }
```

EDIT 2: Having ids as string values, the only solution I see is to manually add each controller as you said, or to add something like this:

```
routes.MapRoute(
name: "Default",
url: "app/{controller}/{action}/{id}",
defaults: new { controller = "Login", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
```

);

This way you don't need to update each route in the future.

Comment: I did try that but like you said it creates an issue with my other controllers going to www.example.com/Product does then go to my login controller and not my Product controller.

Comment: Unfortunately id is a string.  For example it could be companyname.  I have edited my question.

Comment: Maybe you can try with action filters, so if it a company name you can redirect to whatever action you need. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/understanding-action-filters-cs

Answer (score 0):

Please try below routing

```
routes.MapRoute(name: "companylogin", url: "companylogin/{id}", defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });

        routes.MapRoute(name: "default", url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}", defaults: new
        {
            controller = "Login",
            action = "Index",
            id = UrlParameter.Optional
        });
```

Remove other controller specific routing. Now you can navigate to login using 
url : -  www.example.com/companylogin/{id} and all other url redirect default route.